# Expiring URL: Code Igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

Hi I've been trying to Send Urls to customers after order has been made in a e-commerce site, a Electronic Biling will be sent to the customer with a URL of the payment page, Now what I want to do is to make that URL expire in 2 days if he/she has not made any payment. Im using PHP CI and new to it, Any tips will be appreciated guys. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would crate a table in the database to hold tokens ( or store a token with the order ), which would just be a unique ( somewhat random string ) then in that table you can add a created time.  You could also associate this to the order and user that it belongs to.

You would use this token as a parameter for the url, for example

```
www.yoursite.com/payments/abesc90ksade8
```

With the end part abe... the token. then in the controller for that page you can query the database for the token sent, and depending on the current date and the created date, either generate your payment page, or show them and expiration error etc...

If you need more info just ask.

What I like to do to generate tokens is this

```
$token = md5( microtime() );
```

Comment: This is a great solution! I would only add set the expire date with the link. Then have a cron script that cleans the database and use normal error controller and less over head of the table

Comment: Sure, I use a similar approach for reports that get generated, they take some time to run, so the user gets an email with a link like the above, when they are done, and then they can go download them...

Comment: what would be the use of the token?just a unique id?

Comment: yea it's something you can safely send in an email because it's not related to any data but the record it was created for, and it give you a way to assign that link to a particular row, md5 as you may know is a hashing function, that mainly just makes the token look nice and it will always be 32 characters, the microtime makes sure its fairly unique within the application.

Comment: should the token be int or string?

Comment: ah crap sorry for the question it should be string bec of md5 sorry

Comment: you mean for the database field? I would do varchar( 32 )

Comment: microtime is just the current timestamp in seconds with milliseconds, that just gives you something to hash that will generally be unique.

Comment: how will i compare the current data from the data created?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, do you mean how to find the record for the token?

Comment: to know whether to show the payment page or the expiration error page

Comment: oh you would just store a created timestamp in the database and when the user vists you would compare that to the current timestamp - the amount of time ( in seconds ) you want it to be available for here are some examples http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix you have any idea how can i add days from todays date?

Comment: like for example when the user inputs 2 days, those 2 days will be added to todays date and the output will be July 12 2014 thanks